# How to setup a unique click listener for every <img> tag in a table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table has many columns with images as data. I was able to setup a 'common listener' for all of the images in a table row so that when i click any image , the same listener is called.

```
 $('#mytable tbody td img').click(function () {
 // handle event here...
 }
```

How do i have unique listeners for each img in the table row ? Do i use the id tag ?

Comment: is there a specific reason you need a custom handler? you could do it with .each.

Comment: `use ` with `class` instead of `id` for js function

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? if you are wanting to do completely different actions on each image, then it would be best to use an id to bind the click.  If you are just wanting to do the same thing but only on the clicked image, then use `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello,

The best option is to even put an id in each image 
and in your onclick use the id to differentiate the images.

Here is an example

```
<img src="src_image" id="id_image">
```

```
$('#mytable tbody td img').click(function () {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

I hope I have helped!

Comment: do all rows of data get the id for a particular image ? if so , how to find out which row's image was clicked ?

Comment: Putting different id in the images, so you know in which one was clicked.